# Extracting from JSON response

Tags: python, json

I have a Python script that fetches a JSON response:

```
import requests
import json

bitcoin_api_url = 'https://example.com'
response = requests.get(bitcoin_api_url)
response_json = response.json()
print(response_json)
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 'bitcoin', 'name': 'Bitcoin', 'symbol': 'BTC', 'rank': '1', 'price_usd': '4068.19769898', 'price_btc': '1.0', '24h_volume_usd': '9967726932.86', 'market_cap_usd': '71664809254.0', 'available_supply': '17615862.0', 'total_supply': '17615862.0', 'max_supply': '21000000.0', 'percent_change_1h': '-0.42', 'percent_change_24h': '-0.01', 'percent_change_7d': '0.95', 'last_updated': '1553837126'}]
```

How can I extract values from this using Python?  For example, I'd like to ask it for `'id'` and get `'bitcoin'` as a response.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: There already was an image attached mate and an answer below from Scaarus - cheerS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning a list containing a dictionary. Pull the dictionary out of the list, then you can grab individual values from the dictionary.

```
response_json = response.json()[0]
id = response_json['id']
```

Comment: AMAZING - it worked! Thanks so much for your help... pulling the dictionary out of the list was key - read up a bit more on the difference.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

simple code as per your requirement

```
   for i in d:
      print(i['id'])
```